# How to close Application in android

Tags: android, android-intent

Hi i have two activities 1) Login page 2) It shows successfully login, I done perfectly  but my problem is  i want to open new Login page again after close application at second activity please tell me..

Comment: plz finish() before start activity of succesfully login

Comment: Please explain correctly. what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Allright you can do it like this:
do this inside your `SecondActivity`:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this,FirstActivity.class);
    intent.setFlafs(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();    //finish Second Activity
}
```

Hope I answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

you can call finish method when starting successfully login activity. So , when you come back again you will see the login page activity.

Comment: thank you but in between two activites i am using broadcast receiver for incoming call if i use finish second time on wards it does not call broadcast receiver

Comment: in between mean.?. where you are setting your broadcast receiver .?. In first or second activity.?

Comment: broadcast receiver send second activity

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent activity= new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);

finish();            //This is used to close first activity

startActivity(activity);
```

Answer (score 0):

I will provide you with the exact and working solution ,this will definitely work.

Create a Activity logout and in that write this code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Logout.this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("Exit me", true);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
```

MainActivity is where you want user to go after logout.

and then in each and every activity write this code.

```
if( getIntent().getBooleanExtra("Exit me", false)){
            finish();
            return; // add this to prevent from doing unnecessary stuffs
        }
```

This will Completely Exit your android application and also all the activities will get finished.